# Рекурсия, задача про ханойские башни

Tags: java, алгоритм, рекурсия

Это задача на ханойские пирамиды реализована через рекурсию.
Необходимо его дописать и вставить значения в `exchange(?,?,?,?)` 
вот сам код :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("i'm in onCreate");
        int[] arg = {1,2,3};
        main(arg);
    }
    public static void main(int[] arg){
        Stack<Integer> from = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> help = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Integer> to = new Stack<>();
        from.push(3);
        from.push(2);
        from.push(1);
        System.out.println("print from = " + from);
        exchange(from, help, to, from.size());
        System.out.println("print to = "+ to);


    }

    private static void exchange(Stack<Integer> from, Stack<Integer> help, Stack<Integer> to, int count) {
        if (count > 0){
            exchange(?,?,?,?);
            int biggest = from.pop();
            to.push(biggest);
            exchange(?,?,?,?);
        }
    }
}
```

что я понял и что я сделал:

1.Так как я компилировал в *android studio* то без метода `onCreate` ни куда, он запускается первым, массив `arg` создан для запуска последующих методов.

2.Я понимаю что *Stack* организован по принципу *FILO*.

3.Методы `push` и `pop` кладём и удаляем из стека соответственно.

4.В особенности непонятно как работает метод `exchange`.

5.В `exchange(?,?,?,?)` подставлял значения в первом случае `exchange(from,help,to,3)`, во втором `exchange(to,help,from,1)` после чего происходит зацикливание программы.

Answer (score 3):

Рекурсивно решаем задачу «перенести башню из n−1 диска на 2-й штырь». Затем переносим самый большой диск на 3-й штырь, и рекурсивно решаем задачу «перенеси башню из n−1 диска на 3-й штырь».

```
private static void exchange(Stack<Integer> from, Stack<Integer> help, Stack<Integer> to, int count) {
    if (count > 0){
        exchange(from,to,help,count-1); // перенести башню из n−1 диска на 2-й штырь
        int biggest = from.pop();
        to.push(biggest); // переносим самый большой диск на 3-й штырь
        exchange(help,from,to,count-1); // перенеси башню из n−1 диска на 3-й штырь
    }
}
```

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.83.D1.80.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) в помощь:)